# Wanting to set DropDownListA back to default value when a selection is made in DropDownListB

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on creating a web application to solve some internal tasks and am needing some different filter options. I have two drop down lists, but I am having difficulty in filtering by one or the other. Filtering one works fine, but if I want to filter by the other instead I would like to reset the filter value on the first.

Currently, it looks like it is trying to filter by both at the same time unless a value is manually set back. I am filling these values from a database query in my controller and that is working properly. I am not familiar with javascript or jquery really, and not sure if I will have to start learning that route as I get deeper into projects like this.

```
<label>Filter by Customer: &nbsp;</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedCustomerName, Model.CustomerNames, "All", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    <label>Filter by Office: &nbsp;</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedOffice, Model.OfficeNames, "All", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, to do what you ask without reloading the page, javascript is required.

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced in writing out javascript/jquery functions and don't really know where to begin. I am looking at it now, but any additional direction is appreciated.

Comment: You will need a javascript function hooked into the onchange event for the dropdownlist. In that function you can set the selected value for your dropdownlist.

Comment: I added the function to my onchange. It looks like it is working, but it is also clearing the value from the other dropdown before a selection is made. Not sure if this is the best way to do this. It looks rough but it is working as intended.

`<script>
        $(document).ready(function myFunction() {
            $("#customerDropDown").click(function () {
                $("#officeDropDown").val("All");
            });
            $("#officeDropDown").click(function () {
                $("#customerDropDown").val("All");
            });
        });
    </script>`

Comment: You are hooking into the click event. You want the "changed" event I think.

Comment: That was it exactly! Thanks!

Comment: Never trigger a form submit in the `change` event if a dropdown! You allow the users to make their selection and have a separate submit button (and consider user who use the keyboard to navigate through options)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding a function and then calling it from my onchange event.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function myFunction() {
        $("#customerDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#officeDropDown").val("All");
        });
        $("#officeDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#customerDropDown").val("All");
        });
    });
</script>

<label>Filter by Customer: &nbsp;</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedCustomerName, Model.CustomerNames, "All", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();myFunction();", @id = "customerDropDown" })
    <label>Filter by Office: &nbsp;</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedOffice, Model.OfficeNames, "All", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();myFunction();", @id = "officeDropDown" })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via JS, like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function myFunction() {
        $("#customerDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#officeDropDown").val('');
        });
        $("#officeDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#customerDropDown").val('');

        });
    });
```

or try this..

```
$(document).ready(function myFunction() {
        $("#customerDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#officeDropDown").text('');
        });
        $("#officeDropDown").change(function () {
            $("#customerDropDown").text('');
        });
    });
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it will change the value of the other drop down for just a second, then when the page refreshes it goes back to the value it was before. Not sure why it isn't resetting properly. It works on .click, but .change is not acting as expected.